# Spritekit game freezes for a second the first time it retrieves a high score

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, freeze

edit:  I've found that my game freezes while it retrieves the high score for the first time AND it freezes everytime a new high score is archived.  Is there a less intensive way of doing this that won't freeze my game? Thanks.

I've been looking around for reasons why a game might freeze during a first collision.  The game does not freeze when the ball collides with objects that do not cause the player to lose, but rather the first time that the player loses.  All I found online was that playing an audio file without properly preloading it could be the cause.  In order to verify my music isn't the issue, I removed my background music from the game entirely and the problem persists.  Below is the code that is called when the game freezes.  Again, the freezing only occurs the first time this code is called.  I'd appreciate any sort of help on this. Thanks.

The gameOver function:

```
    func gameOver() {

        state = .FSGameStateEnded
        myScore.highScore = score
        if retrievedHighScore.highScore < myScore.highScore
        {
            SaveHighScore().ArchiveHighScore(highScore: myScore)
        }
        retrievedHighScore = SaveHighScore().RetrieveHighScore() as! HighScore
        label_highScore.text = "High Score: \(retrievedHighScore.highScore)"
        label_finalScore.text = "Your Score: \(score)"}
    }
```

Here is my code for retrieving and saving high scores:
        class HighScore: NSObject {

```
var highScore: Int = 0

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    highScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("highScore")
}

override init() {
}
```

}

class SaveHighScore:NSObject {

```
var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
var documentDirectory:String = ""
var path:String = ""

func ArchiveHighScore(#highScore: HighScore) {
    documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as! String
    path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("highScore.archive")

    if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(highScore, toFile: path) {
        println("Success writing to file!\(highScore.highScore)")
    } else {
        println("Unable to write to file!")
    }
}

func RetrieveHighScore() -> NSObject {
    var dataToRetrieve = HighScore()
    documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as! String
    path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("highScore.archive")
    if let dataToRetrieve2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? HighScore {
        dataToRetrieve = dataToRetrieve2
    }
    return(dataToRetrieve)
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try using Instruments to measure how much your code spends on each function? `gameOver()`, `ArchiveHighScore()`, etc.?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do that, but I just commented out the entire high score section in gameOver and now the freezing is gone.  Is there a quicker / less intense way to retrieve a high score?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what "retrieving high score" entails. Are you retrieving it from the internet? Potentially lengthy tasks should be run on a separate, background thread.  Search for "Grand Central Dispatch", "dispatch_async".

Comment: @ThomasKeegan I think you should save  myScore.highScore not  myScore. You can also save just score var

Comment: also get rid of that as! so you don't force unwrapping your score. Use if let to unwrap your optionals

Comment: I would suspect `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` and try to resolve the path at startup. (Why is `SaveHighScore` a class? You never store an instance of it. You could just as well, or better, use two normal functions.)